# java Program error. Anyone knows the reason?

Tags: java

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\USER\eclipse-workspace\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: MyClass.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Comment: Add `package com.hello;` at the top of file before declaring class.

Comment: Thanks. By adding a package name, then class, it worked.